# What the purpose of writing Javascript like exports.default = (0, _createHelper2.default)(pure, 'pure', 1)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found there are some expressions in some libs like this:

```
exports.default = (0, _createHelper2.default)(pure, 'pure', 1)
```

Seems like it has no difference with `_createHelper2.default(pure, 'pure', 1)`

So what is the purpose of writing like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a *small* difference: The value of `this` used when calling `_createHelper2.default`:

With

```
exports.default = (0, _createHelper2.default)(pure, 'pure', 1)
```

`_createHelper2.default` will be called with `this` set to either the global object (loose mode) or `undefined` (strict mode).

With

```
_createHelper2.default(pure, 'pure', 1)
```

`_createHelper2.default` will be called with `this` set to `_createHelper2`.

*(Whether `_createHelper2.default` actually* sees *the `this` value used for the call depends on uses on whether it's a normal function, a bound function, or an arrow function; but that's the difference in the* call *to it.)*

`exports.default = (0, _createHelper2.default)(pure, 'pure', 1)` works by using the *comma operator* to get the function reference *without* associated property information, and then calls that function not via a property access, which bypasses the usual setting of `this`. So it's like doing this:

```
var f = _createHelper2.default;
exports.default = f(pure, 'pure', 1)
```

Comment: why then not calling it with an obvious `call` which is way easier to understand later? `_createHelper2.default.call(undefined, pure, 'pure', 1)`

Comment: @smnbbrv: It may well be minified code, not what a human actually wrote or needs to edit. And some people like a really terse style. (I'm not one of them.) Still, like idioms in many languages, it's perfectly clear once you're familiar with it.

Comment: yes, sure, just looks awkward... I have no problem with similar syntax but I can imagine how the newcomers could hate for it :)